# @Html.ValidationMessageFor not preventing user from to skip Required fields

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller

I have the following code. I have added necessary script files for validating the fields too but the validation does not seem to work. The Required fields can be skipped even if the user has not given any inputs. Could someone please help? thanks!
I have posted a part of the code below. My original code has a lot more dropdown menus and none of the form validation are working.

Model:

```
public class User
{
  
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Gender")]
    public string gender { get; set; }
    
    
}


}
```

View:

```
<body>
<div>

    <div class="card">
        <div class="row" style="padding-left:360px;">
            <p style="font-size:25px; font-weight: bold; text-align:center; padding-top: 50px; text- 
       align : center;"><u>Tell Us a Bit about Yourself! </u></p>
        </div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Register", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "my_form" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new
               {
                   @class ="text-danger"
               })
    
        <table class="row" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gender,
htmlAttributes: new { @class = "register.css" })

                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.gender,
    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))), "Select Gender"
    )

                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>
    model.gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td class="please-no">
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style=" 
       float:right; padding: -20px;">Next</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        }

    </div>
    <script>
@section scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

}

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View(new User());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           
            return RedirectToAction("Register");
        }
        Session["user"] = user;
         return RedirectToAction("PersonalPreference", "Preference");
    }
```

Comment: Is the view you are editing `_Layout.cshtml`? I ask because I see a `<body>` tag and script rendering. I also don't see a `@model` directive at the top stating that the view can expect an instance of `User` to be passed to it. If it's not `_Layout.cshtml`, or a custom layout, which is unlikely if you're just starting out, views don't require a `<body>` to be defined. If you take a look in `_Layout.cshtml` it has a @RenderBody() call in there. That injects the output (i.e. HTML, JS) from your controller(s) into the layout, so you don't need to redefine your layout in each view.

Comment: @JohnH yes I am using a layout.cshtml
I have model of type User in the beginning of my code too. Sorry I should have added it in the question..

Comment: Ok, you have a problem here. By adding that `@model User` directive to your `_Layout.cshtml`, it means you're expecting _every single controller action_ to pass a `User` model. You can see this yourself by creating a new controller, creating a new model type for it, adding the corresponding view, and specifying `@model NewModel` at the top of it. If you navigate to the route, it'll throw because it'll still expect a `User`.

Comment: For what you want to do (i.e. having a registration form that is always visible, no matter what route a user is browsing to), and assuming MVC 5, look into how child actions work, specifically using `@Html.RenderAction()` or `@Html.RenderPartial()` in your layout. This will allow you to move the code you have into a separate `.cshtml` which expects your `User`, whilst you can have other routes working using other models.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution to it. Had to add the following script files. Thanks guys for your time!

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryvalidate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation- 
unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, but please do have a read of my comments at some point.

Comment: @JohnH thank you so much for explaining it! I had no idea about this. However, my website is really small and I just have one action in my controller so it is working for me for now. But I will definitely keep it in mind for future use.